# Complemented sub-spaces in a non-separable space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be Banach space. True or false:

$X$ is non-separable if and only if  there exist at least $2^c$ many complemented subspace in $X$.

Def. A closed subspace $V$ is complemented if there exists  a closed  subspace $W$ with $X=V\oplus W$?